# Subsetting list containing multiple classes by same index/vector

Tags: r, matrix, subset

I'm needing to subset a list which contains an array as well as a factor variable. Essentially if you imagine each component of the array is relative to a single individual which is then associated to a two factor variable (treatment).

```
list(array=array(rnorm(2,4,1),c(5,5,10)), treatment= rep(c(1,2),5))
```

Typically when sub-setting multiple components of the array from the first component of the list I would use something like

```
 list$array[,,c(2,4,6)]
```

this would return the array components in location 2,4 and 6. However, for the factor component of the list this wouldn't work as subsetting is different, what you would need is this:

```
 list$treatment[c(2,4,6)]
```

Need to subset a list with containing different classes (array and vector) by the same relative number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're treating your list of matrices as some kind of 3-dimensional object, but it's not.
Your `list$matrices` is of itself a list as well, which means you can index at as a list as well, it doesn't matter if it is a list of matrices, numerics, plot-objects, or whatever.

The data you provided as an example can just be indexed at one level, so `list$matrices[c(2,4,6)]` works fine.
And I don't really get your question about saving the indices in a numeric vector, what's to stop you from this code?

```
indices <- c(2,4,6)
mysubset <- list(list$matrices[indices], list$treatment[indices])
```

### EDIT, adding new info for edited question:

I see you actually have an 3-D array now. Which is kind of weird, as there is no clear convention of what can be seen as "components". I mean, from your question I understand that `list$array[,,n]` refers to the n-th individual, but from a pure code-point of view there is no reason why something like `list$array[n,,]` couldn't refer to that.
Maybe you got the idea from other languages, but this is not really R-ish, your earlier example with a list of matrices made more sense to me. And I think the most logical would have been a data.frame with columns matrix and treatment (which is conceptually close to a list with a vector and a list of matrices, but it's clearer to others what you have).

But anyway, what is your desired output?
If it's just subsetting: with this structure, as there are no constraints on what could have been the content, you just have to tell R exactly what you want. There is no one operator that takes a subset of a vector and the 3rd index of an array at the same time. You're going to have to tell R that you want 3rd index to use for subsetting, and that you want to use the same index for subsetting a vector. Which is basically just the code you already have:

```
idx <- c(2,4,6)
output <- list(list$array[,,idx], list$treatment[idx])
```

Comment: Thanks. The above works. I sometimes find it difficult to know  how to deal with the data structure which I'm dealing with. For instance, some times things have quotes, sometimes not. I think part of the problem in this case is that I thought I was dealing with a list inside a list but it was an array within a list with a number of other vectors. 

Unfortunately I'm using a package which forces things in a specific format, very confusing. 

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The way that you use for subsetting multiple matrices actually gives an error since you are giving extra dimension although you already specify which sublist you are in. Hence in order to subset matrices for the given indices you can use`my_list[[1]][indices]` or directly `my_list$matrices[indices]`. It is the same for the case treatement `my_list[[2]][indices]` or `my_list$treatement[indices]`

Comment: Ok so just checked my original dataset and in fact the first component of the list is an array with dimensions 91 2 114 whilst second component of the list is a vector of length 114. Sorry for the confusion. Perhaps this would recreate it better:


list(array=array(rnorm(2,4,1),c(5,5,10)), treatment= rep(c(1,2),5))